# RAD Studio Platform selection issue

Tags: windows, delphi, installation, rad, delphi-11-alexandria

After installing Delphi 11 CE, as I could see in videos, a window should come up to download the different platforms.

Instead, I have an error message:

[image]

I tried to search what the problem could be. I changed the source to `sourceURL = https://getit.embarcadero.com`. After that, I have a different message:

[image]

When I tried to open a project, it says:

> This project can not be loaded because required personality Delphi.Personality is not available.

If I open the GetIt package manager, it does not show anything, just no result, like I can not download anything from it.

Please help me solve this issue.

I am using Windows 11, by the way. I tried it on Win 10 in VirtualBox, the result is the same.

I tried it with Wifi and Ethernet, as well.

I rebooted the system, and reinstalled Delphi, bu still have the problem.

Comment: Currently the servers are not available. See https://blogs.embarcadero.com/we-are-experiencing-a-hardware-outage/

Comment: Thank you!

I thought it was solved, as it was 6 days ago.
Is there any way to get it work, as i need to use it for a university project asap.

Comment: You could use Lazarus as an alternative Pascal IDE

Comment: While there are means to do that this for a paid version, there are currently no known ways to achieve that for the CE.

Comment: @Pucusvok, first of all welcome to Stack Overflow! Before I got into Delphi, as I recall, I used [CodeTyphoon](https://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/). I was pretty limited in programing skills (and still am) but as I recall, it worked fine although it is free pascal, not object pascal, but the languages are nearly identical. It looks like whatever OS you use, it should work.

Comment: @Pucusvok "*I thought it was solved, as it was 6 days ago*" - unfortunately, no. It has been *almost* 2 weeks now that the servers have been down, and there has been no information about any progress or ETA for when they will be online again.  The only technical information that has been revealed (in forum posts on Delphi-PRAXiS) is that the outage is due to "*dead hardware*" and that "*it was a cascade of events and multiple affected servers and hardware*".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is due to the server outage, not a problem in the IDE.

Comment: @RemyLebeau True, although the question is very well written and exceptionally clear. Only a side note though. Take it or leave it. I only wanted to point this out as well as the fact that the asker is new here.

Comment: DocWiki seems to be online, but GetIt still has issues. This gives me hope that this event will be over soon. 
 https://ideasawakened.com/post/embarcadero-network-issues

Comment: @RemyLebeau _how is it that a professional company can let it's Trial product (community edition) be completed dead for almost 3 weeks now?_  I don't get it.  Does not inspire confidence in Delphi as a platform if it depends on online connectivity which the parent company doesn't seem to give a toss about fixing...

Comment: @AssadEbrahim it's not just the Community Edition.  Some of their servers are down, which affects more than just installing Delphi (any edition).  Part of the issue is that the installation downloads files from the (currently inactive) servers.  But the broader question of how a professional company can allow their servers be down for so long (and not for the first time) is valid.  But I'm sure that they are working on it. (And as another commenter said, some is now back up.)